# React 17: unable to render element inside of forEach function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have been messing around with react 17 and am looking to implement some basic functionality involving mapping through state with a forEach block and subsequently rendering it, here is some code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Individual from '../components/Individual';

export default function Home() {
    const [archive, setArchive] = useState([]);
    const getArchive = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/v1/archive`)
        setArchive(response.data.data.archive)
        console.log(response.data.data.archive)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getArchive()
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            {archive.forEach((iArchive) => (
                <Individual title={iArchive.title} link={iArchive.link} createdAt={iArchive.createdAt} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Use `Array#map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`as `forEach` won't return any result.

```
 return (
        <div>
            {archive.map((iArchive) => (
                <Individual title={iArchive.title} 
                  link={iArchive.link} createdAt={iArchive.createdAt} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
```